# What is the difference between creating a new guid instance or selecting in Visual Studio tools > create guid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my state script I select Tools > Create GUID > New GUID > Copy

[image: New GUID]

The script is looking like this now :

The guide is not the same as in the screenshot it's just for example.

The problem is that on each object I want to add to this state script format I need manually to generate a new GUID copy it and paste it to the code and it's a bit annoying. So I wonder what is the difference between creating a new guid instance or selecting in visual studio tools > create guide.

This is when creating a new instance :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateGuid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string uniqueGuidID;

    private Guid guidID;
   
    public void GenerateGuidNum()
    {
        guidID = Guid.NewGuid();
        uniqueGuidID = guidID.ToString();
    }
}
```

I wonder why not use the same new instance technic in both cases, why or what the tool for creating guide number 5 is for ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StateTest : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
{
    private State m_state = new State();

    public Guid UniqueId => Guid.Parse("571E6219-DFD4-4893-A3B0-F9A151BFABFE");


    private class State
    {
        public bool s1;
        // bool the kid holding the navi is true
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(m_state);
    }

    public void SetState(string jsonString)
    {
        m_state = JsonUtility.FromJson<State>(jsonString);
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I will edit and update the usage of it :

With this script :

```
using System;

public interface IStateQuery
{
    string GetState();
    void SetState(string jsonString);

    Guid UniqueId { get; }
}
```

In the TestState script I'm using the IStateQuery :

```
public class StateTest : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
```

Then use it like this in the Save and Load methods :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FadeInOutSaveGameText fadeInOutSaveGame;
    public float timeToStartSaving;
    public float savingFadeInOutTime;

    private string saveString;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();
    }

    public void Save(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        var objectsToSave = UpdateObjectsToSave();

        SaveGame saveGame = new SaveGame();
        saveGame.saveObjects = new List<SaveObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
            saveObject.transformSaver = new TransformSaver();
            
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
            saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID = objectsToSave[i].GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID;
            var x = objectsToSave[i].GetComponents<Component>();
            var stateQueryComponent = x.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
            List<KeyToValue> componentsState = new List<KeyToValue>();
            foreach (var z in stateQueryComponent)
            {
                var w = z as IStateQuery;
                componentsState.Add(new KeyToValue(w.UniqueId.ToString(), w.GetState()));
            }

            saveObject.transformSaver.position = objectsToSave[i].transform.position;
            saveObject.transformSaver.rotation = objectsToSave[i].transform.rotation;
            saveObject.transformSaver.scaling = objectsToSave[i].transform.localScale;

            saveObject.componentsState = componentsState;
            saveGame.saveObjects.Add(saveObject);
        }

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveGame);

        if (Folder == null && FileName == null)
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(Folder, FileName, json);
        }
    }

    public void Load(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
       var objectsToLoad =  UpdateObjectsToSave();

        Dictionary<string, GameObject> uniqueIdToObject = objectsToLoad
            .ToDictionary(o => o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID, o => o);

        saveString = SaveSystem.Load(Folder, FileName);

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
            foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
            {
                List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;

                if (uniqueIdToObject.ContainsKey(saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID))
                {
                    var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];

                    objectToSetState.transform.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                    objectToSetState.transform.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                    objectToSetState.transform.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;

                    var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                    var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                    Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);

                    foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                    {
                        zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<GameObject> UpdateObjectsToSave()
    {
        var objectsWithGenerateGuid = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GenerateGuid>().ToList();
        var objectsToSave = new List<GameObject>();

        if (objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count > 0 && objectsToSave.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToSave.Add(objectsWithGenerateGuid[i].gameObject);
            }
        }

        return objectsToSave;
    }

    public IEnumerator AuatomaticSaveWithTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(null, null);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }

    public IEnumerator SaveWithTime(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(Folder, FileName);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using this GUID for? There doesn't seem to be a reference to it anywhere else in your example code.

Comment: depending on the needs. Generating guid thru VS will create a guid which you have to hard code or put in DB somewhere, Guid.NewGuid() will create new guid every time your code runs, so  figure out if you need a static value or dynamic value

Comment: @Charleh you right I updated my question about how I'm using it and where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want, really.

The Visual Studio tool is meant to generate guid you are free to use for whatever you like. It isn't tied to your code in any way. You can of course use these values as static resources for your app, so they will always be the same at runtime.

The `Guid.NewGuid` will generate a new `Guid` value *whenever* your code runs. It will always be dynamic, even for the same object. You run the same app today and tomorrow, you'll get different guids.

Based on your comments, my understanding is that you really are looking for an easier way to inject static guids in your code editor to uniquely identify component types. If that's the case, have a look at the following extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=florians.InsertGUIDCommand

It will allow you to use `SHIFT-ALT-G` to inject a brand new guid value in your code. It should save you a few mouse clicks. ;)

Comment: I got it. so there I will keep using it as before a bit annoying but I guess this is the way I will use it with the static option.  I wonder why there is no way to generate a static guide by code or somehow automatic but I got the idea.